# Writing a vector that doesn't start at 0,0

Tags: vectors, physics

So I have a math problem that involves one vector from $(0,0)$ and another one which I do not know how to write; it starts at 197.7 on the $x$-axis and goes up to $y=30$, I need to add this vector to a different vector but I do not quite know how to write it in rectangular form.

Thanks!

Comment: We need two points to determine a vector. What is the $x$-coordinate of the second point ? Is it $197.7$ ? In this case, the vector you need is $(0/30)$. If it is $0$, the vector you need is $(-197.7/30)$

Comment: it's quite easy to do using components for example, you have vector $AB$ where $A$ has coordinates $(x_1,y_1)$ and $B$ has coordinates $(x_2, y_2)$. Then vector $AB$ can be described by a pair of scalar values (components): $(x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1)$. Find components for both vectors then add corresponding components and you'll get the components of the resulting vector. Finding components is basically the same as moving the start of the vector to the origin.

Comment: I have one vector starting at the origin going to 197.7,30 and i have another vector starts at x=197.7 and going up to 30, i need find the coordinates of the second one in rectangular form and than add it to the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confused about the nature of vectors, or at least the terminology.

Let's consider three *location vectors*, each specifying a point on the 2D plane:
$$\begin{aligned}
O &= (0, 0) = \left [ \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right ] \\
A &= (197.7, 30) = \left [ \begin{matrix} 197.7 \\ 30 \end{matrix} \right ] \\
B &= (40, 20) = \left [ \begin{matrix} 40 \\ 20 \end{matrix} \right ] \end{aligned}$$

We can also define *spatial vectors* (also called Euclidean vectors), between any two points. For example,
$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{a} &= \overline{OA} = (197.7-0, 30-0) = (197.7, 30) = \left [ \begin{matrix} 197.7 - 0 \\ 30 - 0 \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix} 197.7 \\ 30 \end{matrix} \right ] \\
\vec{b} &= \overline{BA} = ( 197.7-40, 30-20) = ( 157.7, 10 ) = \left [ \begin{matrix} 197.7 - 40 \\ 30 - 20 \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix} 157.7 \\ 10 \end{matrix} \right ] \end{aligned}$$

All vectors above use Cartesian coordinates.

It is obviously possible to use other coordinate systems; polar coordinates are one possible choice:
$$\begin{cases}
x = r \cos \varphi \\
y = r \sin \varphi \end{cases}
\quad \iff \quad
\begin{cases}
r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \\
\varphi = \operatorname{atan2}(y, x) \end{cases}$$
where $\operatorname{atan2}(y,x)$ is like $\arctan(y/x)$, except that $\operatorname{atan2}$ includes the correct quadrant also (that depends on the signs of $x$ and $y$). In polar coordinates, $r$ specifies the distance, and $\varphi$ the direction.

In these polar coordinates, $\varphi = 0°$ on the positive $x$ axis, $\varphi = 90°$ on the positive $y$ axis, $\varphi = 180°$ on the negative $x$ axis, and $\varphi = 270°$ on the negative $y$ axis. (Assuming a right-handed coordinate system with positive $x$ axis right and positive $y$ axis up, this means $\varphi$ is counterclockwise from positive $x$ axis.)

---

If we look at OP's question, only one point, $(197.7, 30)$ is well defined. Let's say we call that $A = (197.7, 30)$.

OP mentions another vector starting at $x = 197.7$, and "going up to 30". This is so [Spinal Tappy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven) I can only guess at what is meant by it. Nevertheless, I shall try.

Let's assume the point (or location vector) OP talks about (*"starts at x = 197.7 and goes up 30"*) is $A = ( 197.7 , 30 )$.

OP also mentions *"a different vector"*. Let's say this is $\vec{p} = ( x , y )$. Then,

$$A + \vec{p} = \left [ \begin{matrix} 197.7 + x \\ 30 + y \end{matrix} \right ] = ( 197.7 + x , 30 + y )$$

In English, one might call $A + \vec{p}$  *"$A$ translated by $\vec{p}$"* or *"$\vec{p}$ relative to point $A$"*, specifying the location where $A$ would be if origin was at $\vec{p}$, or where $\vec{p}$ would be if origin was at $A$.

Mathematically, it does not matter whether a vector is a location or spatial vector; the rules and operations are always the same. It only matters to us humans, and not very much even to us because the correct interpretation is always found in the context anyway; and that's why we use the name *vector* for both.

For example, point or location vector $B = (40, 20)$ is exactly the same as spatial vector $\vec{b}$ having length $r = \sqrt{40^2 + 20^2} \approx 44.721$ and direction $\varphi = \operatorname{atan2}(20, 40) \approx 26.565°$, or Cartesian coordinate components $x = 40$ and $y = 20$. In any case, $B = \vec{b}$.

If someone just declares a vector $B = (40, 20)$ or $\vec{b} = (40, 20)$, it does not matter whether they define it as being a location or spatial vector: we can use/interpret it as either, based on the demands of the situation. The math does not care; all that is relevant is that it is a vector in Cartesian coordinates with components $x = 40$ and $y = 20$.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Nik: If this did answer your question, do accept it (by clicking on the check mark, left from the top of this answer).

Comment: I believe there is a typo, should be `(197.7,30)=[197.7;30]` and not `(197.7,30)=[197.7;0]` for vector `OA`