# Describing multiple 3D lines with a single vector equation?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

I understand the process for creating a vector function **r**(t) that describes a line in 3D space. It is also my understanding that vectors can be picked up and moved around (provided I don't change their direction or length) and they are still the same vector. So my question is this:

***If a vector function for a line generates an infinite number of vectors that "trace out" a 3D line, doesn't that same vector function also trace out every single line that is parallel to it in 3D space, since I can technically pick up all those vectors and originate them from any point in 3D space?***

I know that when it comes down to the symmetric equations of a 3D line it wouldn't make sense, but in thinking about what a vector is and how if I say I have the vector <1, 2, 3>, it could be floating anywhere in space...is it just mathematically assumed that when we create vector functions for 3D lines/shapes/etc that they are all referring to vectors that originate at the origin point (0, 0, 0)?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750687/writing-a-vector-that-doesnt-start-at-0-0

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some (understandable) confusion about what a vector is.

This is because a "vector" has different meanings in different contexts.

In the basics, a "vector" is an element of a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space). A prototypical example of a vector space is $\mathbb{R}^3$. Elements in $\mathbb{R}^3$ look like $(1,2,3)$ or $(-1,1,7)$, and you can draw them as arrows *starting at $(0,0,0)$*.

Now comes the confusing part: Vectors are often used to represent some quantities, such as force applied to an object, velocity of an object, flow of a fluid, etc. These vectors are actually *tangent vectors*, i.e. they belong to the [tangent space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) of the coordinate system/manifold used to model your problem.

They still "start" at "$(0,0,0)$", but this is the $(0,0,0)$ of your *tangent space*, not the origin of your whole model. When people say that you can "move a vector around, and it is still the same vector", they mean it (I hope) in the same way as when I buy two loafs of bread, they are *the same* in the sense that they have the same size and nutritional value and taste etc., but they are not *the same* in the sense that if I eat one, the other not eaten by me.

Slightly more confusing still, is that if the coordinate system/manifold is just $\mathbb{R}^3$, people tend to identify the tangent space with the manifold itself.

To correctly describe a *tangent* vector, you should give *both* the base point and the direction. For example, you can consider the vector $(1,2,3)$ with base point $(3,4,5)$. The line described by this tangent vector is then given by $\mathbf{r}(t)=(3+1t,4+2t,5+3t)$. This is a different line than if the base point is different.